# Best method for this study design

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, anova, spss, research-design

I have 7 independent variables age (continuous variable),
body mass index (continuous variable), gender (catagorial variable), department (catagorial variable), hours/day on computer (catagorial variable), hours day sitting or reclining (continuous variable), hours/day typing(continuous variable) and two dependent variables symptom severity scale (continuous variable) and functional status scale (continuous variable)

Sample size 100

The research is about carpal tunnel syndrome (CTS), I want to determine the associated factors with CTS among college students.

An author recommended to use this method: multivariate multiple regression but there is no free guide online for this method in spss software.

Is using separate one way anovas for the independent catagorial variables and sperate simple linear regressions for the continuous independent variables a good method? If not which method should I use?

I'm only familiar with spss software.

Thank you

Comment: As about free SPSS manual, SPSS has very rich online documentation https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/ibm-spss-statistics-28-documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep a multivariate approach and keep your two dependent variables together, looking at the effect of each independent variable separately, you could use one-way MANOVAs. You could also use two-way MANOVAs if you want to test the effect of the independent variables in pairs. I am not familiar with SPSS but a quick google search makes me think these tests are available with documentation. This should work for your categorical predictors. The linear regression would be the way to go for the continuous predictors I think.

However, if you are willing to look a little bit into other analysis programs, you could give a try to R (R Studio is a more friendly interface, entirely free and there is a huge online community support). There you could easily perform a multivariate multiple regression as someone advised you, and consider all your dependent and independent variables in the same model, potentially identifying interactions:
[One example tutorial](https://data.library.virginia.edu/getting-started-with-multivariate-multiple-regression/#:%7E:text=Performing%20multivariate%20multiple%20regression%20in,side%20we%20add%20our%20predictors.) and
[Another good example](https://bookdown.org/egarpor/PM-UC3M/lm-iii-mult.html)

Of course, this is entirely up to you but this type of software is usually much more flexible than SPSS, so if you have time and would like to learn, there is a lot of online materials and tutorials. It can be dauting at first but will surely prove worth it in the long-run.

Hope this helps !

Comment: @thank you very much for your response.